# How do you kill the golden slime?

Tags: halls-of-torment

Occasionally when opening crates, a golden slime will appear. It leaves behind gold coins, and when defeated, explodes in a pile of coins.

However, when hitting the slime no damage numbers appear, and it seems inconsistent which attacks actually cause it to flash. I've managed to defeat it a few times but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong other times.

How do you defeat the golden slime, is there a certain number of basic attacks you need to hit with?